# My query doesn't accept dot in URL

Tags: php, mysql, mod-rewrite

I'm newbie in PHP. When I make post with text for e.g. `Hello.Iam.Number4` post doesn't open.All spaces are converted by default with %20.

I've tried with functions `str_replace` and `preg_replace` to replace `.` with something else `-` or `_` but again post doesn't open.

I've tried with `urlencode` but (space) converted to `+` but `.` again doesn't converted and post doesn't open.

I've this in `.htacess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([^/\.*]+)/?$ index.php?page=news&name=$1 [L]
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Fist, you need to include -_+ in your htaccess file regex, also check out [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) if you are having issues with your MySQL query is getting chars that it shouldn't, also safer so someone doesn't use SQL injection in your link.

Comment: I've put mysql_real_escape_string is there difference between mysqli_real_escape_string ?
Where exactly to add -_+ in rewriterule ?

Comment: ([^/\.*-_+]+) they need to be in the brackets. Also use mysqli in place of the mysql functions as they are newer, more secure, and can be used in object format (which I recommend)

Comment: I've got Error 404 with this ([^/\.*-_+]+) anything at the end needed ?

Comment: ^news/([^/\.\*\-\_\+]+)/?$

Comment: I've managed with ([^-]*) but now some spec characters doesn't work on query like %&$ ?